# Same operation on multiple column in Spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new in scala and Spark and wanted to try some simple concurrent operation on a matrix.

I have an [m, 2] matrix and want to divide each element of a column for the last element of that column.

Here an example of what I want to achieve:

```
 9   25        3  5
 27  10    ->  9  2
 6   15        2  3
 3   5         1  1
```

I can do this whit a simple for-loop, but wanted to do the operation on the columns simultaneously. It is possible in spark or is better to use scala concurrent?

Comment: When you parallelize a dataframe or rdd, the order of input rows is not guaranteed. i.e. last row [3,5] may not be identifiable. Best would be extract the last row separately and then perform the division with the map operation.

Comment: well assuming you read your data from a parquet or a csv file on HDFS then you could do:

`val withIdColumn = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
      inputDataWithoutId.rdd.zipWithIndex.map(ln => Row.fromSeq(Seq(ln._2) ++ ln._1.toSeq)),
      StructType(Array(StructField("id", LongType, false)) ++ inputDataWithoutId.schema.fields)
)`

and doing this would result in deterministically assigning the biggest "id" value to the last row of the input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important question here is what is your data volume? Spark is designed to be used on large amounts of data, too large to be processed or even stored on one computer. If you are wondering if to do something in Spark or on a single machine in plain scala then you should probably stop considering using Spark (if your data volume is not going to grow in the future).

Anyway, assuming for the moment that you are going to have large amounts of data you could do:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, 9, 25),
  (2, 27, 10),
  (3, 6, 15),
  (4, 3, 5)
).toDF("id", "n1", "n2")

val lastRow = df.orderBy(col("id").desc).first()

val result = df.withColumn("n1", col("n1") / lastRow.getInt(1))
    .withColumn("n2", col("n2") / lastRow.getInt(2))

result.show()
```

result:

```
+---+---+---+
| id| n1| n2|
+---+---+---+
|  1|3.0|5.0|
|  2|9.0|2.0|
|  3|2.0|3.0|
|  4|1.0|1.0|
+---+---+---+
```

Please not that this is quite inefficient - even taking the last element is very costly here (not to mention the overhead of launching a Spark job). Doing something like this in Spark might be a good idea only when the data volume is large and you are forced to use cluster computing.

Comment: The reality is that companies are off-loading to Big Data platforms even if volume of data is lower than you may expect - based on costs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification. I'm still a student and we are using spark for a project (and not the best assignment either). The dataset to use is still to decide with the professor. I was wondering on what focus for this type of task. maybe is better using "simple" concurrency?

Comment: Not sure the answer is really applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
val df = Seq((9, 25), (27, 10), (6, 15), (3, 5)).toDF

        val df_final = df.columns.foldLeft(df) {(tempDF, colName) => {
            tempDF.withColumn(colName, (col(colName) / 
             lit(df.select(colName).collect.last.getInt(0))).cast("Int"))
        }}
```